# Windows 8.1 Loading unsigned driver - can't disable signature verification

Tags: driver, loading, windows-8.1, unsigned

H ello

I just installed Windows 8.1 and wanted to develop custom drivers for it. So I tested a sample and build it for x64.

My problem is that I can't disable signature verification.

- When windbg is debugging Windows 8.1, I can't load the driver even though it is msupposed to be loaded anyway. I checked the DebugFlags in the registry : no problem.
- In bcdedit testsigning = yes, integrityservice=yes (boot loader), integrityservices=enable (boot manager), loadoptions = DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS, debug = yes.
- I tried to reboot and use the menu meant that proposes to disable signature verification.
- I've built the project in VS for platform x64 Win8.1 Release, x64 Win8.1 Debug.
- I've built the project in VS with sign mode = Test Sign and Test Certificate = create certificate CN="WDKTestCert blabla".
- On the bottom right corner of the screen, it is written "Test Mode, Windows 8.1 Pro. Build 9600" .
- Host is Windows 8.1 64, Guest is Windows 8.1 64 in hyper-v

My problem is that nothing above works!I still get the message "a digitally signed driver is required".

Do you have an idea of my mistake? I don't know what else I could test to try to make the  loading work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have a solution to this, but I think this question belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: I have tried these steps https://hints-it.blogspot.com/2018/06/permanent-disabling-digital-signature.html and it worked for me

Comment: for me too. but the driver crashed so I had to set force PAE and non-fatal driver crash policy. now it works  :-)  before I got BSOD :-( with paging in non-paged memory